# How does the Barrier SignalAndWait() work in this context?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I just started learning how a Barrier can be used in threading from a tutorial on udemy and the program multi threads the ideology of making tea. I have multiple `barrier.SignalAndWait()` in my program and I'm confused how it works? From my understanding, the program waits when it sees the `SignalAndWait` and it activates the completed phase thingy. I guess from there, this line is printed `Console.WriteLine("Phase " + b.CurrentPhaseNumber + " is finished");` . Is this right or is there more to it?

```
    static Barrier barrier = new Barrier(2, b=> {
        Console.WriteLine("Phase " + b.CurrentPhaseNumber + " is finished");
    });

    public static void Water()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Putting the kettle on (takes a bit longer)");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        barrier.SignalAndWait();
        Console.WriteLine("Pouring water into cup.");
        barrier.SignalAndWait();
        Console.WriteLine("Putting the kettle away");
    }
    public static void Cup()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Finding the nicest cup of tea (fast)");
        barrier.SignalAndWait();
        Console.WriteLine("Adding tea.");
        barrier.SignalAndWait();
        Console.WriteLine("Adding a sugar");
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var water = Task.Factory.StartNew(Water);
        var cup = Task.Factory.StartNew(Cup);
        var tea = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(new[] { water, cup }, tasks =>
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Enjoy your cup of tea");
         });
        tea.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Main program done");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain what's going on:

1. First console output can be "Putting the kettle on..." or "Finding the nicest..." because of multithreading.
2. Then thread of `water` task goes to sleep and `cup` task begins to wait for the awakening of `water` thread via call `barrier.SignalAndWait();`
3. Then when `water` thread wakes up, it begins to wait for `cup` task via call `barrier.SignalAndWait();`
4. Since Barrier has configured for 2 participants we have console output that "Phase 0 is finished"
5. Then again, we can't predict who will output first, so next message will be "Adding tea." from `cup` thread or "Pouring water.." from `water` thread.
6. Then next steps obviously depend on who has started first in the previous step. So if `cup` task started first, it will signal and wait for `water` task via `barrier.SignalAndWait();` and then `water` make a signal to Barrier entity that it's ready via `barrier.SignalAndWait();`.
7. And the same situation as in (4) step, but phase will be incremented and we will have "Phase 1 is finished"
8. Then again, we can't predict who will output first, so next message will be "Putting the kettle away" from `water` thread or "Adding a sugar.." from `cup` thread.
9. `water` and `cup` tasks have finished their work and we will have "Enjoy your cup of tea" and then "Main program done" outputs.

For further reading, I can suggest [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd537615(v=vs.110).aspx) MSDN article with a good example.